# I am not able to set the state of locg variable from the Google api. I need to fetch multiple location latitude and longitude from the Google API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

```
state={locg:''}
componentDidMount(){
  
     
        fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TajMehal&key=xxxx').then(
            response=>response.json()).then
            (json=>this.setState({locg:json}));

            console.log('Locations from Google wdw',this.state.locg)
     
       

}
```

I need to create array of latitude and longitude.But for above code itself not working for hardcoded area.locg is null

Comment: Can you provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code? Also, it looks like you are requesting for Google Maps Geocoding webservice API. You can use [Geocoding Services of Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) for client side requests.

Answer (score 0):

The  reason why you are not seeing the result on the console is because the `fetch` method is `asynchronous`. Meaning, your console log gets executed first even though it is at the end because the fetch method takes more time to finish. And since it is asynchronous, console log does not have to wait for the fetch to finish executing.

So to address this, you must use `async/await`. The word **async** before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. And the keyword **await** makes JavaScript wait until that promise (fetch method) settles and returns its result. This is how it should look like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=TajMehal&key=YOUR_API_KEY')
      .then(response=>response.json())
      .then(json=>{
      this.setState({locg:json});
      console.log('Locations from Google wdw',this.state.locg);
      });
      console.log(this.state.locg)
  }
```

Here is a working sample for your reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-async-await-63982740